Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND using sf org login jwt and with proxy
I can login using salesforce jwt on my laptop with direct internet connection, no problem.
Here are the commands,
token=<omitted>
url=https://testing-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com
user=email@gmail.com
alias=any1
sf org login jwt -i $token -f server.key -o $user -r $url --json -a $alias --dev-debug

But when I started with the company server and with proxy, it started to have this errors below,
[20:15:55.746] DEBUG (sf:oclif:MyDomainResolver): Re-trying dns lookup again....
[20:15:56.750] DEBUG (sf:oclif:MyDomainResolver): Attempting to resolve url: testing-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com
[20:15:56.774] DEBUG (sf:oclif:MyDomainResolver): An error occurred trying to resolve: testing-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com
[20:15:56.774] DEBUG (sf:oclif:MyDomainResolver): Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND testing-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com
[20:15:56.774] DEBUG (sf:oclif:MyDomainResolver): Re-trying dns lookup again....
[20:15:57.775] DEBUG (sf:oclif:MyDomainResolver): Attempting to resolve url: testing-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com
[20:15:57.793] DEBUG (sf:oclif:MyDomainResolver): An error occurred trying to resolve: testing-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com
[20:15:57.793] DEBUG (sf:oclif:MyDomainResolver): Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND testing-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com
[20:15:57.793] DEBUG (sf:oclif:MyDomainResolver): Re-trying dns lookup again....

It will throw that errors for a long time until I break it with ctrl-c.
proxy settings:
no_proxy=.domain.com,localhost,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
https_proxy=http://test.corp.domain.com:8080
NO_PROXY=.domain.com,localhost,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
HTTPS_PROXY=http://test.corp.domain.com:8080
HTTP_PROXY=http://test.corp.domain.com:8080
http_proxy=http://test.corp.domain.com:8080

Testing of curl: all ok
$ curl testing-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com
$curl test.salesforce.com
$ curl login.salesforce.com

Please help, thanks!

I add these,
npm config set https-proxy http://test.corp.domain.com:8080
npm config set proxy http://test.corp.domain.com:8080
npm config set noproxy .domain.com,localhost,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
npm config set strict-ssl false.  Didn't seem to help.  My server proxy I can download any files from github or any.

Do you have node in your path? Could you try node -p 'require("dns").lookup("[your domain]", function(){console.dir(arguments)})' ? (I assume you didn't actually target "testing-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com", because I can neither resolve this.) What OS, by the way?

It's node:latest, debian.  I'm getting this on your node cli, "[Arguments] {
'0': Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND [salesforce.com]
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:109:26) {
errno: -3008,
code: 'ENOTFOUND',
syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
hostname: '[salesforce.com]'
}
}"

I have the same error "errno: -3008, code: ENOTFOUND" on google cloud cli/vm/docker but sf org jwt login is working there.  On my laptop the node cli of yours a success "GetAddrInfoReqWrap {
callback: [Function (anonymous)],
family: 0,
hostname: '[salesforce.com]',
oncomplete: [Function: onlookup]
}
[Arguments] { '0': null, '1': '10.223.36.129', '2': 4 }
"
